# Крон не выполняет функцию

Tags: linux, cron

`/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/сайт.ru/httpdocs/cron.php`

Пароль `TVKrM8WO`.
Ввожу `/usr/bin/php` `/var/www/vhosts/сайт.ru/httpdocs/cron.php?=TVKrM8WO`

Ошибка:

```
execv("/bin/bash") failed
system error: Permission denied
```

Не пойму в чем проблема.

Comment: Не вполне в курсе, откуда тут /bin/bash, но аргументом для интерпретатора php указывается имя файла. У вас есть файл с именем `cron.php?=TVKrM8WO`? Это именно имя файла и оно допустимо для многих файловых систем. Если вам нужно вызвать `cron.php` с передачей параметра - то это делается иначе. Как именно - зависит от скрипта.

Comment: Нужно просто запустить крон, Пробовал с паролем и без, не выходит.

Comment: у крона нет пароля (если рута не считать). Да и запускается крон (если это именно то, что нужно), где то так systemctl start cron

Comment: @KoVadim крон нужно запустить с хостинга сайта. Но я попробовал и все равно ошибка

Comment: У Вас вся проблема в том, что нам нужно слишком много догадаться, что бы Вам помочь. Но у меня есть подозрение, что раз это скрипт, который уже работает на сайте через браузер (иначе бы Вы аргумент не писали бы), то может его и запускать также? то есть, в крон нужно добавить что то вида `curl -s http://сайт.ru/cron.php?=TVKrM8WO > /dev/null`